# Ios UIImageController delegate undeclared error

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

I know this question asked several times on this.
but I follow both method to solved undeclared identifier self.

I declared @interface in .m class

[image]

Comment: you have to declared delegate methods on imagepicker then it will be solved

Comment: Why are you writing this in C/C++ method? Is that a .mm file? Write it in a objective-c method. Your problem will get resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are facing these errors because you wrote it inside a C++/C method. If you write it inside a objective-c method, your problem should get resolved.

```
- (void)cameraCapture {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    picker.delegate = self;
}
```

You can write it in a C/C++ method in the following way.

```
void cameraCapture(void* object) {

    YourCurrentViewController *vc = (__bridge YourCurrentViewController *)object;

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    picker.delegate = vc;
}
```

Call it from a Objective-C method in the following way.

```
CameraCapture(1, "imgName", (__bridge void *)self);
```

Calling a Objective-C method from C/C++ method.

```
void CameraCapture(long cCameraClient, const char *imgName, void* object) {

    SATController *vc = (__bridge SATController *)object;
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Also, you can't directly access `self` from a C++ method. You need to pass it to the function. That's the reason for the input `void *object`. A `void*` is a pointer that has no associated data type with it. It can hold address of any type and can be typecasted to any type.

Comment: correct. I didn't recognise this. But can you please explain how to call this method from c/C++ method.?

Comment: Thanks for answer. but I am new on this, So, I want to learn this. Do you have any reference link for this?

Comment: I suggest you to read apple's documentation on `toll-free bridging`. `void *` means it points to any object, kind of similar to `id` in objective-c. I suggest you to go through an awesome C++ book and apple's documentation on Core-Foundation objects. Also, please upvote :D

Comment: You should need to update you answer, I want to call objective c (ios) method from a c/c++ method. You mentioned vice-verse flow . :O

Comment: I didn't have any object kind of things. see my question for reference. I tried your method. it didn't work. (Void *object) ??

Comment: @NovusMobile, let me check and get back to you

Comment: @NovusMobile, I rechecked everything. It works. Let me edit my answer to suit your need.

Comment: CameraCapture(1, "imgName", (__bridge void *)self); I am getting error.

Comment: how can you have `self` written in the last code (Calling a Objective-C method from C/C++ method) ?